# Selecting resources to improve reading for upper-intermediate level?

Tags: mandarin, learning, reading

There is a great question on '[how to practice reading for beginners](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/225/62)' at the moment that's got a lot of really useful answers, and so I figured I'd ask for some useful things closer to my level. Does anyone have good resources for improving reading for upper-intermediate level?

I probably understand 70-80% of what I read in the newspaper, but generally the news is pretty dry. What types of materials (not specific titles) would people recommend to help with improving my reading skills?

Comment: How many words is 70-80%?

Comment: According to this tool on the Nciku blog (http://blog.nciku.com/blog/en/?p=2132) I know around 2000-2500 characters. Probably around 3000+ words? Hard to judge, hence the percentage.

Comment: **For visitors**: If you're looking for resources visit the question [Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-chinese).

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend

- 思想与社会 (can't find a link, sold in Taiwan)
- [博雅汉语 （upper levels）](http://product.dangdang.com/product.aspx?product_id=8981611)

and I would also recommend preteen/teen books like Harry Potter and Twilight. The story isn't too complicated, and you get a chance to enhance your reading speed and smoothness level. I read Percy Jackson and Twilight. The story of Twilight was a little too cheesy for me, but I did learn a lot of new expressions and could read page after page without stopping.

Comment: are these physical books? or online resources?

Comment: Would you be able to link to these? Cheers!

Comment: Both are books, but couldn't find a link to the first one. It might be considered advanced level even, I had to look up some of the English translations for the vocabulary (!)